# Help me to find the second limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ with $x_1>4$ and $x_{n+1}=3+\frac{4}{x_n}, n \ge 1$.
>
> Prove that  $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=4$ and find  $\lim_{n\to \infty}( \frac{x_{2n+1}+x_{2n}}{8})^n$.

I proved that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=4$, and for the second limit I wrote $$\left(\frac{x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}}{8}\right)^n=\exp\left\{n\ln\left(\frac{x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}}{8}\right)\right\},$$ but I don't understand how to calculate this. Please help!

Comment: The limit is 1. See below my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of proof** : **step 1**:  $ \ln(1-x)=-x-x^2-\cdots -x^n+ o(x^n)\ $, so you have to determine the limit of $$ n(x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}-8)$$

**Step 2** : From a certain point $N$, $x_n\in[3,5]$ so (with $f(x):=3+\frac{4}{x}$) 
$$|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|=|f(x_{n})-f(x_{n-1})|\leq \sup_{c\in[3,5]}|f'(c)||x_{n}-x_{n-1}|< C |x_{n}-x_{n-1}|< 2 C^{n-N}$$
 with $0<C<1$, for $n>N$. So, for $2n>N$, 
$$ |x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|\leq 2 C^{2n-N} $$
 **sept 3**: from the particular form of that equation, it is easy to prove that the subsequence $x_{2n}$ is decreasing to $4$  (since $x_0>4$) and $x_{2n+1}$ is increasing to $4$ (and $x_p>0$ or all $p$).
So, $x_{2n+1}\leq  4\leq x_{2n}$ and 
$$ |x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}-8 |\leq |x_{2n+1}-4|+|x_{2n}-4|=|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|\leq 2 C^{2n-N}$$
so 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}-8) =0$$
You can conclude.

Comment: @Surb thanks :)

Comment: @Surb Because of $x_{2n+1}\leq  4\leq x_{2n}$ we have $$ |x_{2n+1}-4|+|x_{2n}-4|=|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|$$ (draw a picture)

Comment: Yes, sure ! Good job :-) (+1)

Comment: @Surb The same demonstration works for $$\lim_{n\to \infty}( \frac{x_{2n+1}+x_{2n}}{8})^{n^k}$$ for some $k>0$ fixed, so there was some room to torture students a bit more :)

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think about using mean value theorem (and you really nicely solve this problem, I really like it). But without more indication, I hope that you recognize that your first *hint* was not enough :-) I think that here the real trick was the mean value theorem. As a futur hint, something as : Taylor + Mean Value Theorem  would have been perfect (and not only Taylor) :-) Anyway, good job ! :-)

Comment: @Surb yes, I agree, it was not a complete hint, but the point was to put the OP on the start of a road : the point was to focus on the speed of the convergence of the sequence (and not losing time with $\ln$ or $\exp$), which is, I think, quite classical for this type of sequences.